# Are Wacker oxidations tolerant of carbonyl groups?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, organic-oxidation

I was wondering if there was anything in the mechanism of a Wacker oxidation that would interfere with ketones or aldehydes already present in the molecule. Ketones and aldehydes can't be oxidized any further under normal circumstances, so I think it should be tolerant of these groups, but I am unsure.

Comment: Aldehydes can be further oxidised rather readily